# Loading a bmp from resource

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, mfc, loadimage

I'm trying to load a bitmap from resource instead of a file location.  I'm using visual stuidos and I have imported the same bitmap into the rc.  The LoadImage returns a NULL when I try with the resource version.  Is my syntax wrong? or am I missing additional steps?  Please point me in the right direction I'm trying to learn.  Thanks in advance.

```
HBITMAP mhbitmap;

// Loading from a file works
mhbitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, L"sblue.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
mpiccontrol.SetBitmap(mhbitmap);
if (mhbitmap == NULL) {
    MessageBox(L"null", L"from file", NULL);
}
```

The load from file version shows the image, but the resource version does not show the image.

```
mpiccontrol.SetBitmap(mhbitmap);

// My attempt at loading from resource
mhbitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE("IDB_BITMAP1"), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, 0);
if (mhbitmap == NULL) {
    MessageBox(L"null", L"from rc", NULL);
}

mpiccontrol.SetBitmap(mhbitmap);
```

Comment: You must set the first parameter of LoadImage to the instance of the executable that contains the resource.

Comment: @john thank you that fixed the problem by using AfxGeIinstancehandle()

Answer (score 1):

`MAKEINTRESOURCE` macro accepts integer resource id so it should be `MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1)` where `IDB_BITMAP1` is a resource identifier macro (probably from `resource.h`). You should also call `GetLastError` to figure out failure reason.

Comment: I have made the correction of taking off the quotation marks, but it is still not showing the image.  The "resource.h" does have the definition of IDB_BITMAP1.  GetLastError() is telling me the last operation was completed successful.  Am I missing anything else?  Thanks

Comment: Seems like your problem is elsewhere.